# Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL) - Compiling Essentia

Tags: python, encoding, utf-8, windows-subsystem-for-linux

Upon installing WSL on my windows machine, I'm trying to compile essentia via ubuntu terminal using the following code:

`python3 waf configure --build-static --with-python --with-cpptests --with-examples --with-vamp`

I am getting the error:

"SyntaxError: Non-UTF-8 code starting with '\xa6' in file /root/waf on line 2, but no encoding declared; see https://python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/ for details."

I opened the waf file on Notepad++ and changed the encoding to UTF-8. Didn't help.

I then got into the code and replace `# encoding: latin-1` with

`# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-`.
Didn't help.

I copied the file to a new python file, fixed the spacings manually and saved it with the same name. Didn't work.

I would appreciate if anyone help me fix the issue. Many thanks.